# Databinding a label in C# with additional text?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Is there an easy way to databind a label AND include some custom text?

Of course I can bind a label like so:

someLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.someBindingSource, "SomeColumn", true));

But how would I add custom text, so that the result would be something like:
someLabel.Text = "Custom text " + databoundColumnText;

Do I really have to resort to custom code...?

(maybe my head is too fogged from my cold and I can't see a simple solution?)

TIA for any help on this matter.

Comment: You should tag this question for the specific UI tech (winforms I guess).

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Added the tag

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer. How do you make sure that you save only the databoundColumnText, without the "Custom text"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always use Binding.Format event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx

> The Format event is raised when data
>   is pushed from the data source into
>   the control. You can handle the Format
>   event to convert unformatted data from
>   the data source into formatted data
>   for display.

Something like...

```
    private string _bindToValue = "Value from DataSource";
    private string _customText = "Some Custom Text: ";
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Text",_bindToValue,null);
        binding.Format += delegate(object sentFrom, ConvertEventArgs convertEventArgs)
                              {
                                  convertEventArgs.Value = _customText + convertEventArgs.Value;
                              };

        label1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, just tried it and works like a charm. THANKS! 
(can't add a score, because I'm a newbie on this form... Oh well, next time)

Comment: Sheez, who would've guessed the transparent check item to be the thing to click... Thanks again SKG!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you make sure that you save only the databoundColumnText, without the "Custom text"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any simple way, but what should work is a derived class with an extra property that returns the modified Text.

```
class FooAppendedText : FooText
{
  public String AppendedText { get { return this.Text + " xyz"; }}
}
```