# Update entire Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner at C# who's decided to create a textbased adventure game in a Winform, but I've been struggling with updating the form whenever it needs to update. In the past, I have used `something.Invalidate();` to update an image, but apparently that doesn't work for an entire form.

I have a set of labels that display text based on an integer and whenever the value of the integer updates, I'd like the form to show that.

What I have tried thus far:

```
public partial class GameWindow : Form
{
    public void buttonInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Basic.HP = Basic.HP++;
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

While the HP updates, the form doesn't show it. Is there anything else I should use than `Refresh();`? A lot of googling mostly resulted in explanations about Backgroundworkers, but do I really need another thread for something as simple as this?

Comment: Couldn't you just set the text of the labels to the integer value when it updates?

Comment: What is a HP, what is Basic?  Current question is not answerable.\

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Basic.HP is just a name of an integer.

Comment: _HP is just a name of an integer_ Then why should anything be updating?

Comment: There's a label that displays the value of the integer. Already fixed it with the answers below, though.

Comment: `Basic.HP = Basic.HP++;` doesn't make sense. Just use `Basic.HP++`. Now you're assigning the current value of `Basic.HP` to `Basic.HP`, and afterwards increment `Basic.HP` by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make a separate routine for updating values, that you call after every value change. IE: (Note - I don't program in C#):

```
public partial class GameWindow : Form
{
    public void buttonInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Basic.HP = Basic.HP++;
        updateValues();
    }

    public void updateValues()
    {
        hp.text = HealthInteger;
        basic.text = BasicInteger;
    }
}
```

And call this for evey value change.

Comment: A great workaround that worked, can't believe I didn't think of this earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A label can't be bind to a string value like an image can be to a picture box.

The simplest solution here is too explicitly set the Text property of the label each time your HP property is changed :

```
private void RefreshFormWithModel(Basic basic)
{
    labelHP.Text = basic.HP;
}

public void buttonInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Basic.HP = Basic.HP++;
    this.RefreshFormWithModel(Basic);
}
```

If you really want complex binding, [here is some lectures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935431/databinding-a-label-in-c-sharp-with-additional-text)

Comment: Basically the same solution Asryael proposed. Works great and I still can't believe I didn't think of this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the class name of `Basic` is just `Basic`

in the class `Basic`

```
private int hp;
public int HP
{
    get { return hp; }
    set { hp = value; HP_Changed(); }
}

public event EventHandler HPChanged;
private void HP_Changed()
{
    if (HPChanged != null) { HPChanged(this, new EventArgs()); }
}
```

in the `GameWindow`

```
//where ever you create a new Basic, add to the event handler
Basic Basic = new Basic();
Basic.HPChanged += Basic_HPChanged;

private void Basic_HPChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Basic b_sender = (Basic)sender;
    int NewHealth = b_sender.HP;
    //Update whatever value needs to be updated, here
}
```

Then whenever the HP of the Basic is changed, it will fire an event in the GameWindow to update the appropriate field.