# Databinding PictureBox to relative path in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a winform that pull data from database into a DataGridView and Databind it to several text box and a PictureBox. I have a databinding and data loading method to reload and rebind when there is change in the data as below.

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            DataTable dtDS = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dtDS = prodController.GetData();
            dgvProduct.DataSource = dtDS;
        }
private void DataBinding()
        {
            txtProductID.DataBindings.Clear();
            txtProductID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dgvProduct.DataSource, "ProductID");
            txtProductName.DataBindings.Clear();
            txtProductName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dgvProduct.DataSource, "ProductName");
            ...
            bxImage.DataBindings.Clear();
            bxImage.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", dgvProduct.DataSource, "ImagePath");
        }
```

At first I stored the absoluted path of the image in the database as string and it worked fine binding the data into the control. But after that I want to only store the image name in the database, the image themselves are moved to an Image folder in the Application startup folder so that I can load the Image like this:

```
bxImage.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\Image\Student\" + imagePath);
```

I followed [Databinding a label in C# with additional text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935431/databinding-a-label-in-c-sharp-with-additional-text) to add like below to my DataBinding method:

```
var binding = new Binding("ImageLocation", dgvProduct.DataSource, "ImagePath");
            binding.Format += delegate (object sentFrom, ConvertEventArgs convertEventArgs)
            {
                convertEventArgs.Value = Application.StartupPath + @"\Image\" + convertEventArgs.Value;
            };
            bxImage.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

It worked as first but after each time the LoadData and DataBinding are called the string keep adding onto each other making the path invalid. Even if I called the DataBinding clear and reset the format it still adding each time the methods is called. Is there a way to properly do this or should I use CellClicked method of DataGridView to get the image to load into the PictureBox?

Comment: So, if you set a breakpoint in the delgate and look at `convertEventArgs.Value` it piles up the path data?? Weird!  Could you test for StartsWith as a workaround?

Comment: This might seem dumb but where should I put the StartsWith?

Comment: Before modifying the Value, maybe like `if (!convertEventArgs.Value.StartsWith(Application.StartupPath))..` - But this would be just a workaround. Better find the reason for the multiple adding..!

Comment: I don't know if that would work since for example, the application is store in C drive in folder Project, the first time the Binding method is called the Value would be like this: C:\\Project\\Image\\Picture.png, but the second time it become like this: C:\\Project\\Image\\C:\\Project\\Image\\Picture.png. Since they both start the same it would still result the same

Comment: Well I don't know if it is a good idea anyway, but I wrote a __negated__ condition (`!`). The real question is (besides finding the original cause) if the image name itself would be correct..

Comment: Thank you!!! I did not realized it got a negated condition at first. I assigned the ```convertEventArgs.Value``` to a string and checked it using the condition and now it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is long overdue but I should update the answer for anyone who stumble upon this problem the same as me. Thanks @TaW for the answer. In the `binding.Format` change the code to this:

```
String path = convertEventArgs.Value.ToString();
if (!path.StartsWith(Application.StartupPath + @"\Image\"))
{
    convertEventArgs.Value = Application.StartupPath + @"\Image\" + convertEventArgs.Value;
}
```

This should prevent the string to be added each time the DataBinding is called and help bind the data to the control properly.